# PrimeFaces dataTable convert values for showing in a view

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a question based in the following situation.
I have a backing bean that create a matrix with ints, in rows, columns and cells (tablaBean). I have no problem displaying it in a jsf view. Each one of those ints, it´s an ID of differents objects. How can I do, if I want to show in my JSF view, instead of ints, some attributes of the objects?

This is my dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable var="rowName" value="#{tablaBean.rowNames}"  rowIndexVar="rowIdx">
     <p:column headerText="Alumnos:">
         <h:outputText value="#{rowName}"/>
     </p:column>

     <p:columns var="colName" value="#{tablaBean.colNames}" 
                      headerText="#{colName}" columnIndexVar="colIdx">
         <p:panel>
             <h:outputText value="#{tablaBean.data2D[rowIdx][colIdx]}"/>
         </p:panel>
     </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

So for example:

`tablaBean.data2D[1][1]=3`

But I don´t want to show the number "3" in my view.

I want to take that number and show the Person.name of my object `Person.id=3`;

Hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create in your backing bean method returning person name:

```
public String getPersonNameById(int idPerson) {
    return myDao.findPersonById(idPerson).getName();
}
```

Use it in xhtml:

```
<h:outputText value="#{tableBean.getPersonNameById(tablaBean.data2D[rowIdx][colIdx])}"/>
```

Comment: Watch out. If this method is accessed like a getter and the dao method does actually access the database and **not** cache the value, it might be an expensive operation

Comment: That is interesting @Kukeltje. What do you suggest for this?

Comment: Just like you would otherwise do…  Add a simple 'cache' to your bean in the form of a `HashMap` or similar and populate that 'lazily' (and clear it at the right times if needed) or use second level caching in your db layer.